# Total percentage from different rows

Tags: sql-server-2012

With the following code I'm not getting the total percentage but the percentage for each value that is not "U".

How do I change the code to get the total percentage?

```
SELECT grade, (COUNT(grade)* 100 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM studied)) AS Score
FROM studied
WHERE grade !='U'
GROUP BY grade
```

Comment: Does `grade` contain any NULL values?

Comment: No it doesn't contain any NULL values.     
For example: first row shows grade A Score 50, and second row shows grade B score 25, and U is 25 but it's not shown. I want to add A+B so it shows 75

Comment: Hi, Did you run the SQL I provided as it is or did you change Student to studied? My answer had Student table name instead of studied but now I have updated the answer so it should have correct SQL using your table name

Comment: Hello again. I changed the table so it matched mine, returned blank with only column title names.

Comment: I've just attached a screenshot from my SQL Server Management Studio. That may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will return a list of values: *grade* and *score*.

*Grade* will show you all available grades but U. The *Score* value will show you total percentage of the corresponding grade (**including** U). If you would like to have *Score* as a percentage of grades **excluding** U the following SQL should work

```
SELECT grade, (COUNT(grade) * 100 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM studied WHERE grade !='U')) AS Score
FROM studied
WHERE grade !='U'
GROUP BY grade
```

The screenshot below show test data and the query result

[image]

**EDIT**

From your last comment is looks like this SQL should do the work:

```
SELECT (COUNT(grade) * 100 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM student)) AS Score
FROM Student
WHERE grade !='U'
```

It will return you a total percentage of all grades excluding U. Using dataset from the screenshot it will be 92 (which is 92%)

Comment: It ignores U when counting the total percentage and I'd like to return the percentage as a total and not in different rows. For example 2 A, 1B and 1 U returns the Score value of 75. Atm I get A 50, B 25.